# igraph.layout() return layout object, what's the value means?

Tags: python, layout, igraph

I am trying to get the coordinates generated by igraph.layout() in order to use it in visio, when I print layout by below codes:

```
layout = g.layout()
    for x, y in layout:
        print(x, y)
```

I got value like this:

```
1.2230564790485627 -0.4834739024310033
0.51892608517449 0.7690039083284886
-0.6403134985089377 0.8541555622346718
-1.0218655354809427 -0.012596628945430581
-0.17617924212950495 -0.8100312091957422
-0.055807134621198726 0.07949325446849974
```

Could someone can tell me what is this coordinate relative to?

Comment: Hi, please have a look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to improve it. Then you will increase the chance that someone can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout contains the x-y coordinates for where the vertices are to be plotted. However, the plotting function does not actually plot at these locations, at least in the default behavior. By default, plot will rescale these x-y coordinates so that they are between -1 and 1. In other words, the x's are transformed by

```
2*(x -min(x)) / (max(x)-min(x))  - 1
```

The y's undergo a similar transformation before they are plotted.